# Import CSV File With Field Including Commas In Quotes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, fgetcsv

I am importing the following data from a CSV file, whose formatting I have absolutely no control over:

```
CampaignName,"""keyword""",441,11683,3.77%,2.99,112.82,"1,318.02",1.7,12,109.84
```

As you can see, one of the fields has a long number with a comma separator, though the value is enclosed in "..."

The data is imported into SQL using the following piece of code:

```
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
            $import="INSERT into ".$date."_keywords(Campaign,Keyword,Clicks,Impressions,CTR,CPC,CPM,Cost,Position,Conversions,Cost_per_conv) values('$data[0]','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]')";
            mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
        }
```

Even though the long number is within quotes, fgetcsv doesn't seem to be able to handle it, and as a result saves the number as $1 and drops the rest of the quoted text.

It does pick up all the remaining fields correctly - so it doesn't seem to be just supposing that the , is a separator and the 318.02 is the next value.

**Question is**, how do I get the full number to get added to the database?

Edit: I have read the other thread about dealing with commas in CSV files and this file already has the data in double-quotes as that thread suggests, so that's not the issue.

Comment: fgetcsv() has a bunch of extra arguments to define separators, quotes, etc... use them.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: I tried using the enclosure argument as follows:

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "\"")) !== FALSE) {

It made no difference

Comment: Also tried: while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",", '"')) !== FALSE) { ...... Still doesn't make a difference... it's picking up the value as $1 and ignoring the ,318.02

Comment: Have you ensured that the data type is correct in SQL?  What do you have it set as?

Comment: The data type is set in SQL as float(9,2) - should be OK. And I did read the other thread, but all that one seems to suggest is to put the data in double quotes, which it already is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any problem with the CSV parsing. It's a type coercion issue at the MySQL level. You need to strip the comma out of `1,318.02` before inserting into your column of type `float(9,2)`. You should insert `1318.02`, not `1,318.02`.

Instead of:

```
... $data[8] ...
```

do this:

```
... str_replace(",", "", $data[8]) ...
```

Incidentally, you may have some [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) vulnerabilities in the code you've posted, depending on the source of the CSV data. Using PDO prepared statements is advised.

Comment: Brilliant! That worked. I had to do the following in the insert statement: floatval(str_replace(',', '' , $data[8]))

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing the issue...  What version of PHP are you on?

```
$crapData = 'CampaignName,"""keyword""",441,11683,3.77%,2.99,112.82,"1,318.02",1.7,12,109.84';

var_dump(str_getcsv($crapData));
```

Provides me the following output:

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "CampaignName"
  [1]=>
  string(9) ""keyword""
  [2]=>
  string(3) "441"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "11683"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "3.77%"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "2.99"
  [6]=>
  string(6) "112.82"
  [7]=>
  string(8) "1,318.02"
  [8]=>
  string(3) "1.7"
  [9]=>
  string(2) "12"
  [10]=>
  string(6) "109.84"
```

}

Can see it live [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UBDHEG).

Comment: The data is being pulled from an uploaded CSV file. Isn't fgetcsv the preferred function to parse a file?

Comment: Also, I just double-checked the SQL db, and it has definitely imported the number as 1.00 instead of 1,318.02

Comment: Six of one, half a dozen of the other.

Comment: Maybe your issue then has nothing to do with parsing the CSV data then and is instead related to the column data type or not inserting the string rather than a float.  Can't tell from here.

Comment: The data type is set in SQL as float(9,2). Do you reckon it should be a string because the filed is in "..."?

Comment: Tried that too - still no difference :(

Comment: Try decimal as the data type

Comment: No luck still - imported it as 1.00